# exchange columns based on some conditions

Tags: awk

I have a text file with 5 columns. If the number of the 5th column is less than the 3rd column, replace the 4th and 5th column as 2nd and 3rd column. If the number of the 5th column is greater than 3rd column, leave that line as same.

```
1EAD    A   396 B   311
1F3B    A   118 B   171
1F5V    A   179 B   171
1G73    A   162 C   121
1BS0    E   138 G   230
```

Desired output

```
1EAD    B   311 A   396
1F3B    A   118 B   171
1F5V    B   171 A   179
1G73    C   121 A   162
1BS0    E   138 G   230
```

Comment: What if they are equal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk '{ if ($5 >= $3) print $0; else print $1"\t"$4"\t"$5"\t"$2"\t"$3; }' foo.txt
```

Comment: This assumes input is tab-delimited.

Comment: You can shorten it some and get batter printout like this:  `awk '$5>=$3 {$1=$1;print;next} {print $1,$4,$5,$2,$3}' OFS="\t" file`

Comment: Or just replace the fields `awk '$3>$5{x=$5;$5=$3;$3=x}1' OFS="\t" file`

Comment: That doesn't appear to swap the other two columns.

Comment: In any case, I think my answer is fairly readable and just as short as alternatives.

Comment: @AlexReynolds Your answer is fine, we were just providing alternatives. Also, yes i forgot to change the other columns in my previous comment.This would have been better `awk '$5<$3{$0=$1"\t"$4"\t"$5"\t"$2"\t"$3}1'`